# Delete multiple lines from a file

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I have a file that contains several lines of text.

Example:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 1
Line 2
Line 5
Line 6
Line 1
Line 2
```

I want to remove the repetitions of Line 1 and Line 2. And I want to do it from a command line on Windows (either cmd or Powershell). Is there any simple way to achieve it...?
I want my output as follows...

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
```

And one more thing to mention the repeated lines are always the same but they are in large number.

Comment: OS? What have you tried?

Comment: Windows...I tried on windows

Comment: i recommend install cygwin and use sed, without bash and with powershell it's bad idea.

Comment: If you can sort the file then it's easy to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Select-Object -Unique` in Powershell.

[Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx)

For example:

```
Get-Content test.txt | Select-Object -Unique > new.txt
```

would populate `new.txt` with the unique lines in `test.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The `uniq` command does exactly that: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq

Comment: But I can't omit all the repeated lines I may need some of them...I need to omit only some specific lines of the repeated text

Comment: I don't understand.  Which ones do you want to omit.  Perhaps you should clarify this in the question

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
SET "line="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('sort q22351713.txt') DO (
 IF "!line!" neq "%%a" ECHO(%%a
 set "line=%%a"
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22351713.txt` for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt